# Use Angular's $location to get URL parameters from URL string instead of current URL

Tags: angularjs, regex, url, url-parameters

Can I (re)use Angular's `$location` or another Angular module to get URL parameters from a url? Or do I need to add (yet) another separate JS package  to do this?

I have a URL string which I want to get the URL parameters from (aka searchstring). I know there's logic to do this in Angular.js, because `$location` has the [`search`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) method. This  returns the url parameters part as an object. For instance for a url `https://www.domain.org/cool?minPrice=40&maxPrice=50` I can get the maxPrice value using: `$location.search().maxPrice`.

But this works only for the current url in the browser bar. I'm setting up an ngMock function that has to get url params from a URL passed in as a string parameter. I DON'T want a DIY solution as there is [so much debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) about what is correct, performant, etc due to things you might not think of it at first like:
- bad performance of regexp
- needing to url encode parameters
- order dependence, etc.

So I'd love to get this gift-wrapped. And ideally as an included-in-Angular solution so there's also no work for wrapping things up in an Angular service :P.

Note: If it's not possible I'll probably use [uri.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js), which I used to satisfaction in a non-Angular project a while ago.

Comment: Ever considered using **[`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)**?

Comment: Create an `<a>` element and parse `search` property of that element .... see   http://james.padolsey.com/snippets/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

Comment: Thanks @Goldenowner, I am using ngRoute in current project, but actually prefer [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) myself. But ngRoute does NOT contain functionality for URL parsing as far as I can find in documentation. Please supply an answer if it DOES.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, for the quick reply. That looks like a great viable native option for client side code. I'll go with it for now, however this I still consider this a DIY solution that I'd have to Angular wrap myself. Why can't angular expose this functionality as they have it internally already.